# matplotlib, ipywidgets - How to change position of a quiver object?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I want to change the position of a quiver (or an arrow) object depending on the input of the interaction from ipywidgets scroll.

Here is what I tried:

```
%matplotlib notebook
from ipywidgets import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse, Arrow

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[6,6])
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

x_ar1 = -5 #object distance
dy_ar1 = 2 #boject heightX

object1 = plt.quiver(x_ar1, 0, 0, dy_ar1, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
ax.add_artist(object1)

#mark axis
x_axis, = ax.plot([-10, 10], [0, 0], lw=1, c='k')

plt.xlim([-10,10])
plt.ylim([-5,5])

def update(x = -5, y = 2):
    
    x_ar1 = x
    dy_ar1 = y
    
    object1.X = x_ar1
    object1.V = dy_ar1
    
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    

interact(update, x=(-6,6,0.1), y = (-2,2,0.1))
```

Even though the code works for the height of the quiver (`object1.V`), it does not work for the placement of the object (`object1.X`). I also couldn't see any `set_xy` kind of function being available. Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not currently allowed by matplotlib. See https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.quiver.Quiver.html?highlight=quiver#matplotlib.quiver.Quiver

> The only API method is set_UVC(), which can be used to change the size, orientation, and color of the arrows; their locations are fixed when the class is instantiated. Possibly this method will be useful in animations.

There's an open feature request for this on Matplotlib: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11790